# Panda DF Convert All Dates to YYYY-MM-DD format

Tags: pandas, date, datetime, format

i have data that looks like this stored in a DF and I'm trying to convert the "DATE" column so that all the dates are in the format of yyyy-mm-dd format instead of yyyy-dd-mm as you can see when the date changes by the "TIME" column to a new day (some of the dates not shown are already set to the YYYY-MM-DD format but I'm trying to change all of them to the YYYY-MM-DD format):

```
           DATE  TIME  BAFFIN BAY  GATUN II   GATUN I  KLONDIKE IIIG  \
8778 2016-01-01  1900    8.926278  8.046583  7.649784       7.333993   
8779 2016-01-01  2000    8.817666  4.395097  4.748931       6.672631   
8780 2016-01-01  2100    8.704014  6.384826  7.128692       6.115349   
8781 2016-01-01  2200    8.496358  8.261933  8.166153       6.242737   
8782 2016-01-01  2300    8.434297  4.656991  5.894877       5.781445   
8783 2016-02-01  0000    8.528372  3.056838  3.086056       5.023564   
8784 2016-02-01  0100    8.783731  4.614589  4.894076       5.042875   
8785 2016-02-01  0200    8.572500  3.860174  4.641366       5.174426   
8786 2016-02-01  0300    8.279557  2.076971  2.644479       5.492729   
8787 2016-02-01  0400    8.378920  3.562210  2.806703       5.356025
```

I'm trying to set it the "DATE" column to a datetime column with specifying the format but it does nothing:

```
df2['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['DATE'],format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: `pd.to_datetime` always converts to a standard datetime format. As such, the `format` parameter is the current format of the date in column, not the format you want.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

`pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'], dayfirst=True)`

```
0   2016-01-01
1   2016-01-01
2   2016-01-01
3   2016-01-01
4   2016-01-01
5   2016-01-02
6   2016-01-02
7   2016-01-02
8   2016-01-02
9   2016-01-02
```

Comment: OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 0-01-01 00:00:00 - this is the error message i receive when i try this

Comment: Can you check the years you have in your dateset,  is it between 1977 and 2262 or the data go beyond that?

Comment: the data is just for this period     2016-01-01  0000 - 2016-12-31 2300

Comment: Is it working fine when you use `pd.to_datetime` without any `dayfirst` argument?

Comment: df2 = pd.to_datetime(df2['TIME']) - this yields the error: OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 0-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: There is some problem with you data, see the year in that error message is 01, is this 2001?

Answer (score 1):

consider joining 'DATE' and 'TIME' to get a complete `datetime` column. Assuming both columns are of dtype obj (string), you can combine them using the `+` operator and then call `pd.to_datetime` with a specified [format](https://strftime.org/). Ex:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE': ['2016-01-01', '2016-02-01'],
                   'TIME': ['1900', '0000']})

df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE']+df['TIME'], format='%Y-%d-%m%H%M')
# df['DateTime']
# 0   2016-01-01 19:00:00
# 1   2016-01-02 00:00:00
# Name: DateTime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```